# HTTP Status 401.3 for images in _layouts/images/subfolder running under an upgraded SharePoint 2010

Tags: upgrade, permissions, access-denied

Surprisingly, after upgrading a SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 on one of the dev projects, the images from TEMPLATE/IMAGES/SubFolder don't show anymore, giving 401.3 status in IIS logs. Those from TEMPLATE/IMAGES do show normally.

The Authorization Rules in IIS are Allow All Users for both.

WSS_WPG has the required access to the subfolder (it didn't change during or after upgrade).

I even added a location subsection in web.config. To no avail.

```
<location path="_layouts/images/subfolder">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, replacing the permissions with those of IMAGES helped.

Now the ACL includes

1. CREATOR OWNER
2. SYSTEM
3. WSS_ADMIN_WPG
4. WSS_WPG
5. Administrators
6. Users
7. Trusted Installer